# Create a cluster that uses Pod Security Admission

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kind

I try to configure the API server to consume this file during cluster creation.
My system is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64

kind version is v0.17.0 go1.19.2 linux/amd64

minikube version: v1.29.0

The config file is:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    kind: ClusterConfiguration
    apiServer:
        extraArgs:
          admission-control-config-file: /etc/config/cluster-level-pss.yaml
        extraVolumes:
          - name: accf
            hostPath: /etc/config
            mountPath: /etc/config
            readOnly: false
            pathType: "DirectoryOrCreate"
  extraMounts:
  - hostPath: /tmp/pss
    containerPath: /etc/config
    # optional: if set, the mount is read-only.
    # default false
    readOnly: false
    # optional: if set, the mount needs SELinux relabeling.
    # default false
    selinuxRelabel: false
    # optional: set propagation mode (None, HostToContainer or Bidirectional)
    # see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation
    # default None
    propagation: None
```

When I run:
`kind create cluster --name psa-with-cluster-pss --image kindest/node:v1.24.0 --config /tmp/pss/cluster-config.yaml --retain`

I get (the last step crushes after a long time):

```
Creating cluster "psa-with-cluster-pss" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.24.0)  
 ✓ Preparing nodes   
 ✓ Writing configuration
   Starting control-pane
```

traceback:

```
0226 15:54:45.575727     123 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://psa-with-cluster-pss-control-plane:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:108
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:234
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:421
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:153
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
error execution phase wait-control-plane
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:235
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:421
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
    cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:153
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:856
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:974
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:902
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
    cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
    cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing and reinstalling `Docker`, `docker-ce` and `CNI`. In the procedure of kubelet installation you must configure the docker container.

The error message is because you missed a few steps which are not mentioned in the document procedure. Please go through the procedure for the [container runtime official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker) for more information. Check you may have to reset such as: `kubeadm reset` then use a permanent IP and then run `kubeadm init`.

```
sudo kubeadm reset
sudo apt-get install -qy kubelet kubectl kubeadm
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo mkdir /etc/docker
    
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
    "log-driver": "json-file",
    "log-opts": {
      "max-size": "100m"
    },
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF
     
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint kube-master:6443 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands: `-'systemctl status kubelet'`

`-'journalctl -xeu kubelet'`

Refer to [Kubeadm init fails with controlPlaneEndpoint](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/kubeadm-init-fails-with-controlplaneendpoint/15950) for more information

Also refer to `Kind` **Known Issues**: [Troubleshooting kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/known-issues/#troubleshooting-kind) and also check if [Failure to Create Cluster with Docker Desktop as Container Runtime](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/known-issues/#failure-to-create-cluster-with-docker-desktop-as-container-runtime) for more information.