# The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed

Tags: kubernetes

My DaemonJson:

[image]

and here kubelet args.
kubelet args (KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS) in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf and add a --cgroup-driver flag corresponsing to docker cgroup (in this case cgroupfs).

```
My config file looks like this after the modification:

...
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/e`tc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs"
```

When I run kubeadm init following error comes:

```
root@Master:/home/changan# kubeadm init
I0227 18:21:45.233864    7789 version.go:252] remote version is much newer: v1.26.1; falling back to: stable-1.18
W0227 18:21:45.951807    7789 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.18.20
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 20.10.12. Latest validated version: 19.03
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [master kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.0.110]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [master localhost] and IPs [192.168.0.110 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [master localhost] and IPs [192.168.0.110 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
W0227 18:21:56.997324    7789 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
W0227 18:21:57.002821    7789 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get http://localhost:10248/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
^C
root@Master:/home/changan# sudo apt-mark unhold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
Canceled hold on kubelet.
Canceled hold on kubeadm.
Canceled hold on kubectl.
root@Master:/home/changan# sudo apt-get install -y kubelet=1.21.1-00
sudo apt-get install -y kubeadm=1.21.1-00
sudo apt-get install -y kubectl=1.21.1-00
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12
  liblilv-0-0 libllvm15 libmfx1 libmysofa1 libnorm1 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55 librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5
  libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1
  libvidstab1.1 libx265-199 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 pocketsphinx-en-us
  systemd-hwe-hwdb va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kubelet
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 246 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,812 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 kubelet amd64 1.21.1-00 [18.8 MB]
Fetched 18.8 MB in 6s (2,949 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 181783 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kubelet_1.21.1-00_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kubelet (1.21.1-00) over (1.18.1-00) ...
Setting up kubelet (1.21.1-00) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12
  liblilv-0-0 libllvm15 libmfx1 libmysofa1 libnorm1 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55 librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5
  libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1
  libvidstab1.1 libx265-199 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 pocketsphinx-en-us
  systemd-hwe-hwdb va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kubeadm
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 246 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,985 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,689 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial/main amd64 kubeadm amd64 1.21.1-00 [8,985 kB]
Fetched 8,985 kB in 3s (2,701 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 181783 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kubeadm_1.21.1-00_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kubeadm (1.21.1-00) over (1.18.1-00) ...
Setting up kubeadm (1.21.1-00) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12
  liblilv-0-0 libllvm15 libmfx1 libmysofa1 libnorm1 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55 librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5
  libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1
  libvidstab1.1 libx265-199 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 pocketsphinx-en-us
  systemd-hwe-hwdb va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  kubectl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 247 not upgraded.
E: Packages were downgraded and -y was used without --allow-downgrades.
root@Master:/home/changan# kubeadm reset
[reset] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[reset] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
W0227 18:25:51.987266   11717 reset.go:99] [reset] Unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap from cluster: failed to get config map: configmaps "kubeadm-config" not found
[reset] WARNING: Changes made to this host by 'kubeadm init' or 'kubeadm join' will be reverted.
[reset] Are you sure you want to proceed? [y/N]: y
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
W0227 18:25:53.298451   11717 removeetcdmember.go:79] [reset] No kubeadm config, using etcd pod spec to get data directory
[reset] Stopping the kubelet service
[reset] Unmounting mounted directories in "/var/lib/kubelet"
[reset] Deleting contents of config directories: [/etc/kubernetes/manifests /etc/kubernetes/pki]
[reset] Deleting files: [/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf]
[reset] Deleting contents of stateful directories: [/var/lib/etcd /var/lib/kubelet /var/lib/dockershim /var/run/kubernetes /var/lib/cni]

The reset process does not clean CNI configuration. To do so, you must remove /etc/cni/net.d

The reset process does not reset or clean up iptables rules or IPVS tables.
If you wish to reset iptables, you must do so manually by using the "iptables" command.

If your cluster was setup to utilize IPVS, run ipvsadm --clear (or similar)
to reset your system's IPVS tables.

The reset process does not clean your kubeconfig files and you must remove them manually.
Please, check the contents of the $HOME/.kube/config file.
root@Master:/home/changan# kubeadm init
I0227 18:26:20.176334   12061 version.go:254] remote version is much newer: v1.26.1; falling back to: stable-1.21
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.21.14
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local master] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.0.110]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost master] and IPs [192.168.0.110 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost master] and IPs [192.168.0.110 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
[kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy.
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
```

Comment: This could be for multiple reasons from your log file:- 1. Version mismatch for docker and kubeadm/kubectl version (a warning message is already showing) 2. Network/Linux sse config in your system.

Comment: Hello @ChanGan, Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem with `cgroup driver` docker is using. Check Kubernetes cgroup driver was set to systems but docker was set to systemd. It’s not set to `systemd` which is what kubelet’s expecting.

Change `native.cgroupdriver` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and you should be good to go ahead,refer to my previous [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573204/create-a-cluster-that-uses-pod-security-admission/75580260#75580260) on the similar issue. Also refer to my previous [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131916) related to the version mismatch warning for more information.

The kubeadm reset process does not reset or clean up iptables rules or IPVS tables. If you wish to reset iptables, you must do so manually by using the `iptables command`.

**Below Commands help to remove CNI configuration entries,reset iptables & remove kubeconfig file :**

```
sudo rm -f /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X
sudo rm -f $HOME/.kube/config
```

Refer to [Author:Randy’s](https://teachforworld.com/author/randula/) Teachfor world blog on [How to Use kubeadm reset to Reset Kubernetes Cluster](https://teachforworld.com/reset-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm-reset/) for more information.